# Request alfresco authentication token with ajax POST/GET call (Angular)

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, cors, alfresco

Here is the problem,

I try to get an authentication token from my alfresco community server with a js (angular 4) script. The request seems to be blocked by "CORS header missing"...

The login/password are ok since I can try the login URL directly in my browser and I get the expected result (xml) like this :

https://www.my-url.com/alfresco/service/api/login?u=username&pw=password

I get this as a result :

[image]

Now, I come to my web app and I need to retrieve this ticket from an http call, like this (with angular 4 service) :

```
getTicket(user: User): Observable<boolean>{
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    return this.http.post('https://www.my-url.com/alfresco/service/api/login',{'u':'username','pw':'password'},{headers:headers}).map(response => {
        console.log('response : '+JSON.stringify(response));
    });
}
```

I hardcoded the u/pw variables, I also tried to name them "user" & "password", and I tried GET method too, but nothing changes, the only thing I get back is a Cors problem. Result in console :

> OPTIONS XHR https://www.my-url.com/alfresco/service/api/login
>   [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 39 ms]
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource ... Reason: CORS header
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing.

Request data :

```
Response Headers : 
Allow: "OPTIONS, GET, POST"
Content-Length: "0"
Date : "Wed, 11 Oct 2017 14:37:45 GMT"
Server: "Apache-Coyote/1.1"

Request Headers : 
Host : "www.my-url.com"
User-Agent : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
Accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
Accept-Language : "en-US,en;q=0.5"
Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate"
Access-Control-Request-Method: "POST"
Access-Control-Request-Headers: "access-control-allow-origin"
Origin: "http://localhost"
Connection: "keep-alive"
```

I also tried removing the headers I manually create for the request, but no effect...

Comment: Have you unable CORS in alfresco?

Comment: Hi @Sanjay Patel thanks for your comment. Well I guess its enabled since my http works in browser. Btw i made several searches on how to enable cors in alfresco but found nothing clear/relevant about it... Can you help me to fix this ?

Comment: Which version of alfresco you are using?

Comment: If you are using alfresco 5.2 then put  enablecors-1.0.jar in <alfresco_home>modules/platform folder.  https://community.alfresco.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fartifacts.alfresco.com%2Fnexus%2Fservice%2Flocal%2Frepositories%2Freleases%2Fcontent%2Forg%2Falfresco%2Fenablecors%2F1.0%2Fenablecors-1.0.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How To Enable CORS in alfresco V5.2 ? Put [enablecors-1.0.jar](https://community.alfresco.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fartifacts.alfresco.com%2Fnexus%2Fservice%2Flocal%2Frepositories%2Freleases%2Fcontent%2Forg%2Falfresco%2Fenablecors%2F1.0%2Fenablecors-1.0.jar) 
in modules/platform folder.

Comment: My version of Alfresco is 5.1.0 (r127059-b7) This is not working. I still have this "missing header in response" error... Weird...

Comment: Thanks for your help, you did point me to the right direction, I found this : https://community.alfresco.com/message/812776-authentication-json-parse-error-with-reactjs-using-alfresco-51e-ce-login-rest-api?q=Alfresco%205.1%20CORS#comment-813702 and it solved my issue :)